# How do I use validatepattern for multiple integers?

Tags: powershell

Basically, I need to use validate pattern to validate a few numbers. I need to be able to run .\Myfilename "number" "number" "number" "number" "number" and it should do a few things with those numbers in the script.

An actually example of what I would type is: `.\Myfilename 100 100 20 30 50`

What I can't figure out is how to use validatepattern to assure these numbers are integers.

**This is what I tried:**

```
Param ([ValidatePattern("\d")] $G1 = 0, $G2= 0, $G3 = 0, $G4 = 0, $G5 = 0)
```

**I also tried:**

```
Param ([ValidatePattern("\d\s\d\s\d\s\d\s\d")] $G1 = 0, $G2= 0, $G3 = 0, $G4 = 0, $G5 = 0)
```

To no avail... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe a `ValidatePattern Attribute` is needed in this case, unless there actually is a specific pattern you want the arguments to have. In addition, you don't need to have one parameter per argument. You can have only one parameter and type constraint it to `[int[]]` and have the parameter as [`ValueFromRemainingArguments argument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefromremainingarguments-argument) to make sure you're capturing all inputs.

- Sample **script.ps1**:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [int[]]$Numbers
)

$i = 0

foreach($number in $Numbers)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ArgumentNumber = ($i++)
        Input = $Number
        IsInt = $Number -is [int]
    }
}
```

- Sample Input and Output:

```
PS /> ./script.ps1 123 345 567           

ArgumentNumber Input IsInt
-------------- ----- -----
             0   123  True
             1   345  True
             2   567  True
```

And if you were to use an invalid input such as a `string`:

```
PS /> ./script.ps1 123 345 567 'asd'
```

- `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message` would be:

> Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" to type "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "asd" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""

---

**Note:** By using this method, the input should always follow one of the following formats:

- `<int><white space><int><white space><int>....`, i.e.: `123 345 567`
- `<int><comma><int><comma><int><comma>....`, i.e.: `123, 345, 567`

An input that does not follow this syntax will get you an exception.

- `<int><comma><int><white space><int>`, i.e.: `123, 345 567`

Will get you the following exception:

> Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" to type "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"."

---

`[ValidatePattern("\d")]` is not a valid pattern for what you're looking for (**one or more numeric digits per argument**). `\d` will accept any input that has at least 1 numeric digit:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [ValidatePattern("\d")] $Grade1 = 75
)

"Input was: $Grade1"
```

```
PS /> ./script.ps1 1asd
Input was: 1asd

PS /> ./script.ps1 asd2
Input was: asd2
```

If you want the input to be all numeric digits, the easiest way is to just type constraint the parameter and if really need to use `Validate Pattern`, the pattern for all numeric digits would be **`^\d+$`**:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [ValidatePattern("^\d+$")]
    [int] $Grade1 = 75
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help! I'm a bit new to Powershell, so this is a bit confusing to me still, but I'm going to read up on this! 

I did figure out a way before I read your reply, which was: 
`param (
[ValidatePattern("\d")] $G1 =75, [ValidatePattern("\d")] $G2 =75, [ValidatePattern("\d")] $G3 =75, [ValidatePattern("\d")] $G4 =75, [ValidatePattern("\d")] $G5 =75)`

I will definitely look into what you explained to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RachelD see my last update to understand why `[ValidatePattern("\d")]` will not work. And, happy to help :)